# Detecting palindromes

Tags: java, for-loop

So I'm working on a program that identifies palindromes (words that are the same forwards and backwards). To accomplish this I place the contents of a string into a queue and a stack one character at a time. I then have a for loop compare the entries of the stack with that of the queue to see if they match up. If each character matches than we have a palindrome. Any characters not matching results in the match flag going false and breaking the loop. The problem is that my for loop won't run. The program skips over it completely. In fact it tells me that my "match" variable is unused. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for reading my post.

**
I apologize for my vagueness. Stack and Queue are classes of my own design. They take a String input, divide the String into characters (char type), creating a node for each character and connecting them. Stack is last in first out, Queue is first in first out. blank 1 and blank 2 are empty nodes that act as start markers within each.

```
public void palVerify(String s)
{
    boolean match=true;

    //creates stack
    Stack backward=new Stack(blank1);
    backward.push(s);

    //creates queue
    Queue forward=new Queue(blank2);
    forward.enqueue(s);


    // THIS LOOP WONT RUN

    for (int i=0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if (backward.readTop()==forward.readFront())
        {

            backward.pop();
            forward.dequeue();
        }
        else
        {
            match=false;
            break;
        }

    }

    if (match=true)
        System.out.println("This word is a Palindrome");
    else
        System.out.println("This word is not a Palindrome");


}
```

Comment: Can you provide how you call palVerfiy()? Also you should be giving Stack and Queue a Object type. I'm surprised `backward.readTop()==forward.readFront()` even compiles. What is blank1 and blank 2?

Comment: Do you mean to `if (match == true)`?

Comment: Further to Andy's comment, what you mean is `if (match)`. Please don't fall into the anti-pattern of `if (match==true)`.

Answer (score 1):

You're never evaluating `match` in your code, only assigning to it. That's why you're getting the unused variable warning.

You likely want to evaluate `match` in the if statement on the bottom - replace with `if(match=true)` (which is assigning true to match variable) with `if (match)` (which evaluates the variable and branches based on its value).

On your for loop - it probably is running (you can add a `System.out.println("Here");` to the beginning of it to prove it.  However, you're comparing Strings using `==` - String comparison should use the `equals` method.

I'm not sure what `blank1` and `blank2` are; I assume they're member or static variables declared outside your method.  I don't think your logic to do the detection of the palindrome (comparing `backward.readTop` and `forward.readFront` does what you think it does, unless you're using your own custom versions of `Stack` and `Queue`)

Answer (score -1):

```
public class JustForShow {

    public boolean isPalindrome(String text){
        if(text == null || text.isEmpty())
            return false;

        char []arr = text.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0,y = (arr.length - 1); i<y; i++,y--) {
            if(arr[i] != arr[y]){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String palind = "ABCDDCBA";
        JustForShow jfs = new JustForShow();
        System.out.println(jfs.isPalindrome(palind));
    }
}
```

Comment: Though this provides a (much better) alternative implementation of `isPalindrome`, this doesn't really help the OP know how to solve the problems in their own code..

Comment: I understood his way of doing but there are too many unknowns in his question so i want to provide a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a working solution :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a three-digit integer: ");
    int number = input.nextInt();

    if (number / 100 == number % 10)
       System.out.println(number + " is a palindrome");
    else 
       System.out.println(number + " is not a palindrome");
 }
```

Comment: The OP did not ask for your solution, he asked for why *his* solution was not working.

Comment: This was flagged as low-quality answer. Please try to improve your question. For now, I'll just edit your indentation but other reviewers may be more severe